# How to compile C++ executable using headers

Tags: c++

I have three C++ programs

**factor.h**

```
#ifndef FACTOR_H
#define FACTOR_H

/**
 * Factor an integer n. Prime factors are saved in flist.
 * If n is zero, return -1. If n is negative, factor -n.
 * If n is 1, return 0 and do not save any primes in flist.
 *
 *
 * @param n the integer we wish to factor
 * @param flist an array to hold the prime factors
 * @return the number of prime factors
 */
long factor(long n, long* flist);

#endif
```

**factor.cpp**

```
#include "factor.h"

long factor(long n, long* flist) {

    // If n is zero, return -1
    if (n==0) return -1;

    // If n is negative, we change it to |n|
    if (n<0) n = -n;

    // If n is one, we simply return 0
    if (n==1) return 0;

    // At this point we know n>1

    int idx = 0;    // index into flist array
    int d = 2;      // current divisor

    while (n>1) {
        while (n%d == 0) {
            flist[idx] = d;
            ++idx;
            n /= d;
        }
        ++d;
    }
    return idx;
}
```

**test_factor.cpp**

```
#include "factor.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/**
 * A program to test the factor procedure
 */

int main() {

    long flist[100];    // place to hold the factors

    for (long n=1; n<=100; n++) {
        int nfactors = factor(n,flist);
        cout << n << "\t";
        for (int k=0; k<nfactors; k++) cout << flist[k] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I was able to get this to run by doing

```
g++ -c factor.cpp -o factor
g++ -o test_factor test_factor.cpp factor
```

My confusion is in the second line. When I'm creating an executable for test_factor, how come I only have to call the header file in test_factor.cpp ? How does calling factor.h in test_factor.cpp tell the compiler how the factor function is defined? I just don't get how it automatically recognizes the factor object file I pass in contains the definitions of factor. None of this makes sense to me.

Comment: The compiler doesn't need the definitions. The linker has all the object files and it just searches through them to find the definition.

Answer (score 1):

> how come I only have to call the header file in test_factor.cpp ?

Since you are using factor() in the test_factor.cpp only, you need its declaration, which in your case is provided by factor.h.

In your example, you have included factor.h in factor.cpp also. Technically its not needed there. However it is considered as good practice as it allows compiler to check the declaration (factor.h) against actual function definition (factor.cpp), specifically the number of parameters and their types.

> How does calling factor.h in test_factor.cpp tell the compiler how the
>   factor function is defined?

Its the job of linker to stitch the object file containing code for factor() function and the main() function.

> g++ -c factor.cpp -o factor

This step (g++ -c) compiles factor.cpp to object file named `factor` (its not executable)

> g++ -o test_factor test_factor.cpp factor

This steps (g++ -o) compiles test_factor.cpp and calls the linker to link object code for main() with `factor` generated above into executable `test_factor`.

As a trial you may omit `factor` from second step. It will throw linker errors.

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion of the header is only for knowing the ***prototype*** or the ***symbol*** that is needed for the local file compilation, and not for knowing the definition itself. That is done by combining the object files, in a later part called the ***Linkage***.

During the compilation of a single file, whenever encountering a new symbol (for example, a name of a function), the compiler checks for its *deceleration*, if it encounters in such, it puts a place-mark (kind of *TODO*) in that location, stating that the true reference should be added later. As long as you have the declaration in included header, it is fine with the compiler.

When reaching the stage of combining all the files into one source - the***Linkage*** stage of the compilation, the linker (a part of the compiler) is looking for the real locations of the symbols in the program, and puts the locations instead of these place-marks. If you don't include the ***object file*** containing the ***definition*** of the symbol, you will get a ***linkage*** error:

`Undefined reference to <symbol>`

This means, that the compiler knows the symbol (since you have included the header), but doesn't know the definition. (also common error is having the same function defined more than once: `multiple definition of <symbol>`). This is what the line:

`g++ -o test_factor test_factor.cpp factor`

is doing - compile the file `test_factor.cpp` and link it with the object file `test_factor`.

Comment: @Glassjawed This line is similar to: `g++ test_factor.cpp factor -o test_factor` which means - *compile the file test_factor.cpp, and link it with the object file factor into a new file called test_factor*. This is ***exactly when*** you create the file test_factor